# Two very different user models in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I have two different types of users in my application that uses Devise for authentication using Rails 4 but they have very different fields. One is a Buyer and the other is a Seller. The Buyer must have location and payment information while the Seller doesn't. Initially I thought it would be a good idea to create two separate Devise models but there has to be a better way. I thought about keeping it all in the same table and serializing the Buyer's payment data.

What would be a good solution?

Comment: What's the reason you don't make to different models? They for sure are different objects.

Comment: A lot of problems arise when you have two Devise models apparently

Comment: You'll get helpers for each model like current_seller and current_buyer. But, since you need to separate them anyway, I think this will make it easy for you. I am doing it with users and admin_users. If you hate the idea of two models take a look at [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). It gives you the ability to give users roles, but it's not intended for you use case.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at STI - in short you create one base model called `User` and then two subclasses `User::Buyer` and `User::Seller` (No need for namespacing, but it is recommended). Both models are stored in same table and everything applied to `User` model will affect both those classes. More about STI [here](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)

UPDATE:

If you don't want to have a number of empty table cells, you might use 1-1 association to keep all class-specific details. You can also add a wrapper to encapsulate it completely. It could look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :details, polymorphic: true

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    return details.send(method, *args) if details.respond_to? method
    super
  end
end

class BuyerDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :details

  # buyer_attribute column
end

class SellerDetails < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: details

  #seller_attribute
end
```

You can then mix it with STI:

```
class User::Buyer < User
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    details = BuyerDetails.new
  end
end

class User::Seller < User
  def initialize(*args)
    super
    details = SelerDetails.new
  end
end
```

Then you can simple work using:

```
user = User::Buyer.new
user.buyer_attribute       #=> nil
user.seller_attribute      #=> NoMethod error!
```

Note: You will need to have `details_type` string column on your `User` model as well as `details_id` for polymorphic association to work. For STI, you will need another column `type`.

Comment: Would STI be a good thing to do if the only fields they really share in common are names, email and password?

Comment: BroiSaste, what happens if buyer can be a seller as well and seller can be a buyer as well ? Polymorphic association comes with it's own problems.

Comment: @VijayMeena - Oh wow, that answer is over 7 years ols now :D In that's case STI does not work - instead create a single User model and separate Buyer/Selled models (or BuyerProfile/SellerProfile) that belongs to User.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I use polymorphic relations instead. I keep my User model pretty much for authentication, then make two new models (Buyer and Seller) with the fields they don't share in common. This is very close to BroiSate's method shown above.

Example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :authenticatable, polymorphic: true
end


class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_one :user, as: :authenticatable
  # Add buyer specific fields to this table
end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_one :user, as: :authenticatable
  # Add seller specific fields to this table
end
```

Comment: what if tomorrow requirement changes and a user can be a buyer as well as seller? In my opinion a polymorphic association may not scale well with the change in requirement.